# Microsoft Symbols for debugging purposes on an isolated network

Tags: windows, windbg, debug-symbols

I am trying to setup a symbol server on an isolated network (no internet access) and have connected machines fetch and locally cache symbols for whatever version of Windows they are debugging. I know symchk.exe can pull down symbols but only for the machine being debugged. I want all symbols stored locally and only update the local repo of symbols once a month or so.

I have created a manifest file for the machine about to be debugged but I am unable to load symbols for it. The network does not reach the internet but I am able to bring symbols in and store locally. However, I cannot take the manifest file out of the work environment. I would like to download all symbols so that I can store them locally and update the symbol repo at random.

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a manifest file for the machine about to be debugged [...] I cannot take the manifest file out of the work environment.

If you can't take the manifest with you, it's useless. No need to create the manifest file at all.

There's also no option of asking the official Microsoft symbol server for all symbols and then mirror it completely.

However, you can try to replicate the machine to be debugged. Install the same version of Windows and same applications, then create a manifest from the replicated machine, download the symbols and carry them to the work environment.

You could also ask all your co-workers to do the same for their machines, so you get a larger collection of symbols.

Microsoft has [once published offline symbol packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols). Maybe you find someone who still has them (e.g. I have 16 GB of them)

Comment: We thought about doing what you just mentioned but we wanted exhaust all resources before doing so. Good on you for having your own "symbol store" because that'll be great in an environment that doesn't have internet access. Would you ever host the symbol server or are you keeping those just for yourself? Thanks again for your feedback.

Comment: @polynikes: these 16 GB are rather old, mostly Windows 8 and early Windows 10. Likely not so useful any more. I can send you a USB stick, if you like